An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid
So I have a DRF project that was deployed to AWS Lambda functions, my static/media files are stored in an S3 bucket and I am using CloudFront as a global CDN.
The issue is that in development, everything works fine but when deployed (in production), I can't seem to upload a file without getting this error.
enter image description here
Traceback:
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://6tkguarbg2.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/production/auth/register/

Django Version: 5.1
Python Version: 3.10.14
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'authentication',
 'api',
 'revenue',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'rest_framework_simplejwt',
 'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
 'dj_rest_auth',
 'dj_rest_auth.registration',
 'corsheaders']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/var/task/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/var/task/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/django/utils/decorators.py", line 48, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 143, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/dj_rest_auth/registration/views.py", line 42, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/var/task/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/var/task/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/var/task/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/rest_framework/generics.py", line 194, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/dj_rest_auth/registration/views.py", line 64, in create
    user = self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/var/task/dj_rest_auth/registration/views.py", line 80, in perform_create
    user = serializer.save(self.request)
  File "/var/task/authentication/serializers.py", line 74, in save
    user.save()
  File "/var/task/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 62, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/base.py", line 891, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/base.py", line 997, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/base.py", line 1120, in _save_table
    values = [
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/base.py", line 1124, in <listcomp>
    (getattr(self, f.attname) if raw else f.pre_save(self, False)),
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 338, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 99, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "/var/task/django/core/files/storage/base.py", line 49, in save
    name = self._save(name, content)
  File "/var/task/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 450, in _save
    obj.upload_fileobj(content, ExtraArgs=params)
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 731, in object_upload_fileobj
    return self.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 642, in upload_fileobj
    return future.result()
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py", line 103, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py", line 266, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 139, in __call__
    return self._execute_main(kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 162, in _execute_main
    return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/upload.py", line 764, in _main
    client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=body, **extra_args)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 565, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 1021, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)

Exception Type: ClientError at /auth/register/
Exception Value: An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.


My static and media files settings in the core/settings.py:
STATIC_URL = "static/"

USE_S3 = bool(os.environ.get("USE_S3_STATIC", "False"))

if USE_S3 is True:
    # Use S3 for storing static and media files
    STORAGES = {
        "default": {
            "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage",
            "OPTIONS": {
                "access_key": os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
                "secret_key": os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
                "bucket_name": os.environ.get("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME"),
                "region_name": os.environ.get("AWS_S3_REGION_NAME"),
                # "default_acl": os.environ.get("AWS_DEFAULT_ACL"),
                "custom_domain": os.environ.get("AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN"),
                "querystring_expire": 600,
            },
        },
        "staticfiles": {
            "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage",
            "OPTIONS": {
                "access_key": os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
                "secret_key": os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
                "bucket_name": os.environ.get("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME"),
                "region_name": os.environ.get("AWS_S3_REGION_NAME"),
                # "default_acl": os.environ.get("AWS_DEFAULT_ACL"),
                "custom_domain": os.environ.get("AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN"),
                "querystring_expire": 600,
            },
        },
    }
else:
    MEDIA_URL = "media/"
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")


core/urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("auth/", include("authentication.urls")),
    path("api/", include("api.urls")),
    path("rev/", include("revenue.urls")),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


zappa_settings:
{
    "dev": {
        "aws_region": "eu-west-2",
        "django_settings": "core.settings",
        "exclude": [
            "boto3",
            "dateutil",
            "botocore",
            "s3transfer",
            "concurrent"
        ],
        "slim_handler": false,
        "timeout_seconds": 120,
        "project_name": "proj-backend",
        "runtime": "python3.10",
        "handler": "wsgi.handler",
        "s3_bucket": "proj-django-bucket"
    },
    "production": {
        "aws_region": "eu-west-2",
        "django_settings": "core.settings",
        "exclude": [
            "boto3",
            "dateutil",
            "botocore",
            "s3transfer",
            "concurrent"
        ],
        "slim_handler": false,
        "timeout_seconds": 120,
        "project_name": "proj-backend",
        "runtime": "python3.10",
        "handler": "wsgi.handler",
        "s3_bucket": "proj-django-bucket"
    }
}

I have a getEnv.sh script that gets the environment variables from my AWS Secret Manager:
SECRET_NAME="proj-backend"
ROOT_DIR="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"

SECRETS=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $SECRET_NAME --query SecretString --output text)
ENV_DIR="$ROOT_DIR/.env"
touch $ENV_DIR
echo $SECRETS | jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)")|.[]' > $ENV_DIR
echo "Secrets fetched and stored in $ENV_DIR"

and a load_env.py script that loads those environment variables to the zappa_settings so that those variables won't be exposed to the public in the repo:
import json
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()


def update_zappa_settings():
    # Load .env variables
    env_vars = {
        "DB_ENGINE": os.environ.get("DB_ENGINE"),
        "DB_HOST": os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
        "DB_NAME": os.environ.get("DB_NAME"),
        "DB_USER": os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
        "DB_PASSWORD": os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"),
        "DB_PORT": os.environ.get("DB_PORT"),
        "DEBUG": os.environ.get("DEBUG"),
        "SECRET_KEY": os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY"),
        "USE_S3_STATIC": os.environ.get("USE_S3_STATIC"),
        "AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME": os.environ.get("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME"),
        "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
        "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
        "AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN": os.environ.get("AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN"),
        # "AWS_DEFAULT_ACL": os.environ.get("AWS_DEFAULT_ACL"),
    }

    # Load existing Zappa settings
    with open("zappa_settings.json", "r") as file:
        zappa_settings = json.load(file)

    # Update environment variables in Zappa settings
    zappa_settings["production"]["environment_variables"] = env_vars

    # print(zappa_settings)

    # Save updated Zappa settings
    with open("zappa_settings.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(zappa_settings, file, indent=4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    update_zappa_settings()


and a cd.yml file:
name: Continous Deployment

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      choice:
        description: Choose Operation
        options:
          - update
          - deploy
        type: choice

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"

      - name: Set up virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          source venv/bin/activate
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-west-2

      - name: Setup up Requirements
        run: |
          source venv/bin/activate
          chmod +x ./getEnv.sh && ./getEnv.sh
          python load_env.py

      - name: "${{github.event.inputs.choice}}"
        run: |
          source venv/bin/activate
          zappa "${{github.event.inputs.choice}}" production


The view and urls that the error is coming from:
authentication/views.py:
class CustomRegisterView(RegisterView):
    serializer_class = CustomRegisterSerializer
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, JSONParser]

    def get_response_data(self, user):
        # Generate the tokens for the user
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        access = refresh.access_token

        # Custom response data
        data = {
            "access": str(access),
            "refresh": str(refresh),
            "user": {
                "pk": user.pk,
                "username": user.username,
                "email": user.email,
                "first_name": user.first_name,
                "last_name": user.last_name,
                "is_artist": user.is_artist,
                "bio": user.bio,
                "dob": user.dob,
                "image": user.image.url if user.image else None,
            },
        }
        return data


authentication/urls.py:
from dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth import get_refresh_view

from dj_rest_auth.views import LogoutView  # LoginView
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenVerifyView, TokenBlacklistView

from .views import (
    CustomRegisterView,
    CustomLoginView,
    UserUpdateView,
    PasswordChangeView,
    CustomUserDetailsView,
)


urlpatterns = [
    path("register/", CustomRegisterView.as_view(), name="register"),
    path("login/", CustomLoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path("user/", CustomUserDetailsView.as_view(), name="user_details"),
    path("user/update/", UserUpdateView.as_view(), name="user_update"),
    path(
        "user/change-password/",
        PasswordChangeView.as_view(),
        name="change_password",
    ),
    path("token/verify/", TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name="token_verify"),
    path("token/refresh/", get_refresh_view().as_view(), name="token_refresh"),
    path(
        "token/blacklist",
        TokenBlacklistView.as_view(),
        name="token_blacklist",
    ),
]


My access key ID and secret key is correct. My permissions for my IAM users and roles are correct as well yet I am still keep getting errors.

At a guess, you are using IAM User credentials during development but an IAM Role in production. The former comprises access and secret keys while the latter comprises access and secret keys plus a session token. Your code only passes access and secret keys.

@jarmod Ok, so how then can I pass the session token in my code? I am quite new to the AWS ecosystem.

How are you populating/fetching access key and secret key right now? Is there also an AWS_SESSION_TOKEN?
